# Is there a PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS equivalent for INSERT statements?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, null, pdo

I've got a function that reads data from one database, formats and recombines them a bit and inserts them into another. However, any line with missing data for certain columns should be rejected by the target database. The way I wanted to do this was by putting NOT NULL constraints on the relevant columns in the target table so that the INSERT statements just don't get executed when those values are NULL.

However, on imploding my formatted arrays of source data I use quotes on every value so as to be able to concatenate them with the rest of the sql INSERT string right away. I was planning to use the PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS attribute to convert all empty strings (NULLs in source data) to NULL on INSERT, but now it turns out this only seems to influence the results of SELECT queries, not INSERT statements. Does anybody know an elegant and quick way to tell MySQL or the PDO object to treat all empty strings in INSERT statements as NULL?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle treats empty strings as NULLs. This is not something MySQL does. You can do `array_map(function ($element) { return $element ? $element : NULL; }, $arguments);` to replace before passing to PDO, however. (Or `$element === '' ? NULL : $element` depending on how you want to handle `0` and `'0'`)

Comment: That was going to be my workaround in case it can't be done, indeed, but in that case I would have to replace my implode('\", \"',$values) with a rather less elegant foreach or while loop to avoid my NULL values becoming "null" strings.